# HighCharts Issue with GWT/Bootstrap

Tags: gwt, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am running into the following exception when I try to add a highchart to my page.

Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) @org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeRenderChart(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;ZZLcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)([string: 'Chart', JavaScript object(1855), bool: true, bool: false, JavaScript object(2098), JavaScript object(2099), JavaScript object(2100), JavaScript object(2092), JavaScript object(2095), JavaScript object(2091), JavaScript object(2093), JavaScript object(2094), JavaScript object(2096), JavaScript object(2097)]): Unable to get property 'Chart' of undefined or null reference

I have been using the following chart build just to try to get something to work

```
@Override
    public Widget getChart() {
        if(chart == null) {
            chart = new Chart()
                    .setType(Series.Type.PIE)
                    .setChartTitle(null)
                    .setPlotBackgroundColor((String) null)
                    .setPlotBorderWidth(null)
                    .setPlotShadow(false)
                    .setPiePlotOptions(new PiePlotOptions()
                                    .setAllowPointSelect(true)
                                    .setCursor(PlotOptions.Cursor.POINTER)
                    )
                    .setToolTip(new ToolTip()
                                    .setFormatter(new ToolTipFormatter() {
                                        public String format(ToolTipData toolTipData) {
                                            return "<b>" + toolTipData.getPointName() + "</b>: " + NumberUtils.applyPercentageFormat(toolTipData.getPercentage())
                                                    + "<br />" + NumberUtils.applyCurrencyFormat(toolTipData.getYAsDouble());
                                        }
                                    })
                    );

            chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()
                            .setName("Browser share")
                            .setPoints(new Point[]{
                                    new Point("Firefox", 45.0),
                                    new Point("IE", 26.8),
                                    new Point("Chrome", 12.8)
                                            .setSliced(true)
                                            .setSelected(true),
                                    new Point("Safari", 8.5),
                                    new Point("Opera", 6.2),
                                    new Point("Others", 0.7)
                            })
            );

        }


        return chart;
    }
```

I then add the chart to a DroppableWidget

```
public class DroppablePanel extends DroppableWidget<FlowPanel> {

    private FlowPanel innerPanel;

    public DroppablePanel() {
        innerPanel = new FlowPanel();
        innerPanel.setStyleName("col-sm-6");
        initWidget(innerPanel);
        setupDrop();
    }

    public void add(DashboardWidget widget) {
        innerPanel.add(widget);
    }

    private void setupDrop() {
        SortableDragAndDropHandler sortableHandler = new SortableDragAndDropHandler(innerPanel);
        addDropHandler(sortableHandler);
        addOutDroppableHandler(sortableHandler);
        addOverDroppableHandler(sortableHandler);
    }

}
```

Then add the DroppableWidget to a FlowPanel on the page I want to display the chart on. This is where the error occurs. It appears to have trouble converting the Chart to javascript(I think) I have debugged this thing over and over trying to pinpoint the issue, but can't find anything

I have the following scripts added per other sources with similar issues

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts/highcharts-all.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Not sure what to do. Does anyone have suggestions on things to try or they themselves has experience this issue?

Comment: You should have jquery referenced before the highcharts items.

Comment: made the change, but I still get the same issue.